# Clojure: move item in a list

Tags: list, clojure, position

I have this list:

```
("a" "b" "c" "d" "e")
```

I want to move "d" in the first position:

```
("d" "a" "b" "c" "e")
```

Is there any straightforward way to do this?

EDIT

Thanks for the answers. I had a look into it and I did this:

```
(defn move-item [data item-to-move]
    (conj (remove #(= % item-to-move) data) item-to-move))
(move-item ["a" "b" "c" "d" "e"] ["d"])
```

I am not sure if this is good design, but it does the trick.

Comment: In this case you should post your own answer and accept it.

Comment: (move-item ["a" "b" "c" "d" "e"] ["d"]);=>(["d"] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e")

Answer (score 5):

functions that can be helpful:
1. `rotate`

```
user=> (defn rotate [xs] (cons (last xs) (drop-last xs)))
#'user/rotate
user=> (rotate '(1 2 3))
(3 1 2)
```

2. [`replace`](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/replace)

```
user=> (replace {1 4} [1 2 3 4])
[4 2 3 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need much flexibility, then I'll go for a destructuring solution:

```
user=> (letfn [(des [{:strs [a b c d]}] [d a b c])]
         (des (set ["a" "b" "c" "d"])))
["d" "a" "b" "c"]
user=>
```

Using `set` allows for using the elements as keys, which can be taken apart and named using the `:strs` directive. Then you just return the elements in the order you want.

I guess a macro should allow you to generalize the approach.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn move-last [coll]
    (cons (last coll) (drop-last coll)))

user=>(move-last '("a" "b" "c" "d"))
("d" "a" "b" "c")
```